# Dvd flick audio out of sync problem?

Tags: windows-vista

When I burn a .avi or any other type of file sometimes the audio is out of sync. How can I fix this problem should I burn it at a slow or faster speed.

Please leave a couple of suggestions on how to fix this problem.

Now before you ask the files where already in sync before burning with DVD flick.

Comment: which version of DVD Flick are you using?

Comment: the latest version.

Comment: Burning wouldn't affect the syncing it would be the conversion done before the sync.

Comment: I've had problems with DVD Flick creating DVDs with out of sync audio too, not just from AVI files, but MKVs too.  I've just given up on the tool altogether.

Answer (score 1):

I've had problems with the AVI container and out of sync audio before, some applications just don't handle it very well. Since DVD Flick supports [numerous input formats](http://www.dvdflick.net/features.php), I'd try transcoding it to a different format ([HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/) will do this) then try to reburn.